# UIImagePickerControllerDelegate error

Tags: swift, uiimageview, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode8

So I have this code that will get photos my gallery or use the camera to change the UIImage.

```
@IBAction func tappedCamera() {
    print("tapped camera")

    let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Choose Option", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
            self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
            self.picker.allowsEditing = true
            self.present(self.picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    })
    let galleryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) {
            self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary;
            self.picker.allowsEditing = true
            self.present(self.picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


    })
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        //do none
    })


    optionMenu.addAction(cameraAction)
    optionMenu.addAction(galleryAction)
    optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

But I always get this error, whenever I try to capture a photo or select an image from the gallery.

```
[Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error
```

Comment: 1. When you capture the photo, at did finish picking delegate method, Make sure u cast to *Any* `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]`
2. Implemnt the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` too.

Comment: Where is your delegate method for UIImagePicker didfinishpickingimage??

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by fixing my user defaults. Because somewhere along the code I was messing up with the images, converting them to base64 strings, then saving it to user defaults.